# How do we import dags in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hi im new to **Airflow** , im trying to import my own customize jar as DAG which is generated with **Talend Open Studio BigData**, and im having  some trouble when i import my DAG via the terminal, 
no error is shown up and my DAG is not added to the DAG list in **Airflow UI**

Here is my .py file code :

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

import os
import sys


bib_app = "/home/user/Docs/JObforAirflow/test/test_run.sh"
default_args = {
    'owner': 'yabid',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 29),
    'email': ['user@user.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
    'provide_context': True    }

args = {
  'owner': 'yabid'
  ,'email': ['user@user.com']
  ,'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 25)
  , 'provide_context': True    }

dag = DAG('run_jar', default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='dependency',
    bash_command= bib_app,
    dag=dag)


t2 = BashOperator(
 task_id = 't2',
 dag = dag,
 bash_command = 'java -cp /home/user/Docs/JObforAirflow/test/jobbatch.jar'
 )

t1.set_upstream(t2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy this DAG file to `~/airflow/dags`?

All your `*.py` files need to be copied at `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` where AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

import os
import sys


bib_app = "/home/user/Docs/JObforAirflow/test/test_run.sh"
default_args = {
    'owner': 'yabid',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 25),
    'email': ['user@user.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
    'provide_context': True
}


dag = DAG('run_jar', default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='dependency',
    bash_command= bib_app,
    dag=dag)


t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id = 't2',
    dag = dag,
    bash_command = 'java -cp /home/user/Docs/JObforAirflow/test/jobbatch.jar')

t1 >> t2
```

Comment: Yes of course the .py location is under  `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags`

Comment: I have modified your file a bit, copy paste that file in AIRFLOW_HOME/dags. Restart `airflow-webserver` & `airflow-scheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have `'email': ['user@user.com],` line with non-closed string: `'user@user.com`. If you try to run this code in Airflow, the DAG will fail.
2. As mentioned in another answer, you should place all your DAGs in `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` folder. After you will add the new DAG file, I recommend you to restart your `airflow-scheduler` and `airflow-webserver`

Comment: i did correct that non-closed string mistake thanks ,  but still the same, and as i repleid to @kaxil all my dags are under  `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags`

Comment: Did you reboot `airflow-webserver` and `airflow-scheduler`? I tried to create this DAG on my local machine, and it appears in GUI.

Comment: it works, i did reboot `airflow-webserver` and `airflow-scheduler` twice and my DAG apperas in the UI thanks you